# Elementary Events vs Elements in the Sample Space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, elementary-set-theory

I keep seeing questions in my assignments like

> What is the sample-space for this set, and what are it's elementary events?

For the past couple of assignments, I assumed they were the same thing. It seems like this type of question pops up quite often and I'd like to know the difference between them.

If I were to take a guess at the difference it would be:
**Elementary Events**: Unique events in the sample space.
**Sample Space**: The set of events that are possible.

These are the definitions that I keep seeing for both of these, but to me, the definitions are basically the same.

Comment: Have you seen the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_event)? Is there something about this definition that still leaves you wanting?

Comment: In probability there is a _sample space_ $S$ that consists of all possible _outcomes_.  An _event_ is a subset of $S$ (so, it is a set of possible outcomes).  Judging from Eric's comment above, it seems "elementary event" is an event with just one outcome.  So I agree that "What is the sample-space for this set, and what are its elementary events?" is basically the same question twice, since specifying the sample-space gives all possible outcomes, and specifying its elementary events also requires you to specify all of its outcomes (and then treat them as one-element sets).

Comment: So if we pick a real number in $[0,1]$, the sample space $S$ is given by $S=[0,1]$, and the elementary events are the one-element sets $\{x\}$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.  A non-elementary event $E$ is "the outcome is less than 0.4," which is the same as $E=[0,0.4)$. This event $E$ has an infinite number of outcomes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I keep seeing questions in my assignments like
>
> > What is the sample-space for this set, and what are it's elementary events?
>
> For the past couple of assignments, I assumed they were the same thing. It seems like this type of question pops up quite often and I'd like to know the difference between them.

They are *mostly* the same thing in concept; though technically different.

An event is a set of outcomes.   An atom, or atomic set, is a set of one element.   An atomic event and an outcome are different things; although often *loosely* referred to as though they were the same thing.

The sample space is the set of all outcomes.   Its elementary events are the collection of atomic subsets that partition the space.

$\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ is the sample space for the result of one die roll.

$\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{5\},\{6\}$ are the elementary events of this space.